# Access denied when trying to use Mysqlimport Utility (using Root Credentials)

Tags: mysql

We are trying to import large CSV files through Mysqlimport as described in [This](http://chriseiffel.com/everything-linux/how-to-import-a-large-csv-file-to-mysql/) & [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) article. But even though I am using root credentials I keep getting the following error:

> mysqlimport: Error: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

Below is the command I have used:

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines= --fields-terminated-by=, --columns='company, company_addr, 
city, zipcode, state, phone, fax, email, website, contact_name' --local -u
 root -p dss_databank /data/brick1/web/web/data_files/test_ssh_insert.csv
```

Comment: Can you login to mysql commandline with the same credentials? If yes try using [LOAD DATA (LOCAL) INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) instead, either it will work or you will get the same error message even when logged in, in that case you root account might be missing the `FILE` privilege.